# Ignore a function in OCaml elegantly

Tags: ocaml

I define a function f in utop of OCaml version 4.04.

```
utop # let f = function x -> x + 1;;

val f : int -> int = <fun>
```

When I try to ignore f, I encounter a warning.

```
utop # let a = ignore (f : int -> int); f 2;;

Characters 15-19:                                             
Warning 5: this function application is partial,
maybe some arguments are missing
val a : int = 3
```

Warning 5 is triggered because the expression following `ignore` has a function interface `int -> int`.

`ignore (f 0)` and `if false then (ignore f 0)` work but they are not elegant. I don't want to provide missing arguments to f. Is there any alternative to `ignore`?

The motivation of `ignore` isn't very clear in this dummy example but I do need to use it to avoid other warnings in my real project.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I smell an XY problem (http://xyproblem.info/). Can you explain the real use case?

Comment: If you're not calling the function, why do you even have it in the first place?

Comment: The real use case is that to compile some OCaml code in run time by using ocaml_plugin. The piece of code may or may not call `f`. Given that I don't want to make `f` as a library to my plugin, the best way is to append the code to the definition of `f`. If it doesn't call `f`, compiler will complain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very roughly speaking for expression of the form `e1; e2` is handled by OCaml typechecker as follows:

- If `e1` has a function type `t -> t'`, a Warning 5 is emitted.
- else, if `e1` does not have a type `unit`, a Warning 10 is emitted.

For example,

```
let f x = 
    prerr_endline "some side effect you may want"; 
    (* but you may not want the returned function sometimes *)
    fun y -> x + y

let a = f 1 2; f 1 2;;       (* Warning 10 *)
let a = f 1; f 1 2;;         (* Warning 5 *)
```

The type checking of `ignore e1; e2` is as same as the one of `e1; e2` except one point: it skips the second check: a Warning 10 is not emitted even if `e1`'s type is not `unit`.  The first check for the Warning 5 is still performed:

```
let a = ignore (f 1 2); f 1 2;;  (* No warning *)
let a = ignore (f 1); f 1 2;;    (* Warning 5 *)
```

So `ignore` is designed to remove Warning 10, not 5.  This special handling of `ignore` is coded around `is_ignore` funciton definition of `typing/typecore.ml` in OCaml source code.

If you want to really ignore the Warning 5, I think of 2 methods:

```
let a = let _ = f 1 in f 1 2;;   (* No warning *)

let ignore' _ = ()
let a = ignore' (f 1); f 1 2;;   (* No warning *)
```

The first one is to use a pattern matching with a wild card.  The other is to define your own ignore function `ignore'`.  This is a usual OCaml function therefore the special type checking of the argument of `ignore` which emits a Warning 5 above is not performed.

Comment: What if I don't want to provide missing arguments to f?  It works fine in this dummy example, but sometimes the missing arguments can be difficult to construct and `f` may raise exceptions to some improper arguments.

Comment: I see your point that the compiler will always complain if `ignore` is followed by a variable of function interface. I wonder if there's any alternative to `ignore`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the warning by replacing the `ignore` call by a `let _` construct:

```
let a = let _ = (f : int -> int) in f 2;;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define your own ignore function that operates over arrow types as in the following :

```
let ignore_fun (f:'a -> 'b) = ()
```

That way you don't need anymore to pass an argument to **f** and the following wont produce a warning.

```
let a = ignore_fun (f : int -> int); f 2;;
```

Comment: Warning 27: unused variable f. The variable f is not used in ignore_fun so warning 27 is triggered.

Comment: I could have written ````let ignore_fun (_:'a -> 'b) = () ```` instead but i dont find it clearer

Answer (score 0):

The answer by camlspotter is fine and you should just accept it.
I would just like to add a third solution: Wrap the offending function into a tuple

```
let a = ignore (f,()); f 2;;
```

or a list

```
let a = ignore [f]; f 2;;
```

or whatever takes your fancy.